# solving a pair of iterated differential equations

Tags: python, iteration, differential-equations

Ive got a pair of differential equations that I've learnt how  to solve:

> ```
> dc/dt=r*c+c^2-c^3-b*c*u,
> du/dt=-g*u+(b*c*u)/2,
> ```

where r,b,g are constants (no assumption on r but b and g are positive). So my code to solve these are:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


b=2
g=0.1

def func(z,t):
    c = z[0]
    u = z[1]
    dcdt = r*c+c**2-c**3-b*c*u**2
    dudt = -g*u+0.5*b*c*u
    return [dcdt,dtaudt]

#inital conditions
z0 = [1,0.2] #u[0] =!0.0

#time points
t = np.linspace(0,20,100)

#solve ODE
z = odeint(func,z0,t)

#seperating answers out

c = z[:,0]
u = z[:,1]
```

I hope this is the right way to go about it. If not, please let me know of my mistake. I have two questions.

1. Is there any way we can make my function dependent on (c,u,t) rather than (z,t)?
2. I need to iterate these equations. So I need a variable `n=6`

where we can get python to solve the differential equations for dcdt[i] for i up to 6. I want this because I want to change the equations so that dcdt[i] might depend on dcdt[i-1] or dcdt[i+1] etc.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your formulas do not match the computation in the code. The code is missing a value for r.

Comment: Sorry, I've set r to be -0.2 in the code.

Comment: What do you mean with "*need a variable n=6*"? A state vector with dimension 6 that consists of 3 components `c` and 3 components `u`?